# mailhost in Net::SMTP perl

Tags: perl, email, smtp

i'm new to perl. Currently I'm working on a perl project which needs to send out email automatically. The servers in which the perl scripts locate only have Net::SMTP installed. When I read Net::SMTP's doc i got confused - in the constructor we need to specify mailhost. Is this the sender's mailhost or receiver's?

Also I would be grateful if anyone could give me some links which cover how to use Net::SMTP. Compared with other email modules, this is really not developer friendly.

Comment: Is using `Net::SMTP` a strict requirement? I found [`Mail::Sender`](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Mail::Sender‎) very convenient.